# FindMinimum not accurate

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider the function

```
f[B_, d_] := -158.57189 + 982.533102 B^2 - 5.6768579 d + 895.1968 d^2 + 
   B (-18.7772 + 655.02206 d);
```

`FindMinimum` finds a minimum as

```
NumberForm[FindMinimum[f[B, d], {{B, 0}, {d, -1}}], 10]
>> -158.66171062483005`, {B -> 0.009678954771281474, d -> -0.00037034932854333405`}
```

However, I can do better than that:

```
NumberForm[f[B, d] /. {d -> 0.000055555} /. {B -> 0.009833}, 10]
>> -158.6614819506207
```

Why does this happen (the numbers seem large enough so numerical precision shouldn't be a problem), and is there a way I can find the true minimum?

Comment: The numbers are negative so the largest magnitude is the minimum.

Comment: What `FindMinimum` returns is in good agreement with `N[Minimize[SetPrecision[f[B, d], Infinity], {B, d}], 200]`.

Comment: @BobHanlon That does it, this is what happens when you are running on no sleep!